# Resize Stack View

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, uistackview

I have a UILabel and a Switch on storyboard, I use Stack View to group them, however,after embedded into a horizontal Stack View, I am not able to resize the stack view but only can move it around. Why?

(I am using XCode 8 + Swift 3)

[image]

**===== UPDATE ======**

Thanks guys suggesting for adding constraints, but .... I added constraints, but I still would like to see the constrainted layout on storyboard instead of messed up layout.

E.g. I added constraint to leading and trailing space to be 8 pixel away from parent, but I see red line which xcode gives to indicate the actual layout is not showing in the constraint way. That's the problem, I can only drag the stack view, but I want to resize it to match my constraint so that it looks same as that in real device.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add constraints to set the the placement of the StackView.  To set the distance between the two controls, simply set the spacing as I've done in the image below (Spacing = 50):

[image]

Comment: Please see my update, I don't want to add constant value for spacing because I would like the space to be proportional to device screen. I added constraints to have the leading and trailing space of the stack view to be 8 pixel away from parent, but still, storyboard show what my screenshot shows, the messed up way.

Comment: Try setting the distribution to Equal Spacing.  Also, set a constraint to the top of the Stack View.  I suspect the red error signal is the result of not specifying a y coordinate.  The distribution is above the Spacing Attribute that is depicted in the image.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the width constraint to change the width.

Answer (score -2):

In Interface Builder, start by dragging out a vertical stack view, and add the flowers label, image view, and edit button. Then set up the constraints as shown.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I added constraint, but I still would like to see the constraint layout on storyboard instead of messed up layout. E.g. I added constraint to leading and trailing to be 8 pixel away from parent, but I see red line which xcode gives to indicate the actual layout is not showing in the constraint way. That's the problem, I can only drag the stack view, but I want to resize it to match my constraint so that it looks same as that in real device.

Comment: This was copy-pasted from Apple's docs and does not answer the question.